# How to change ripple effect from right to left on this button code

Tags: html, css

[Link to button Code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_buttons_animate2)

**Hey i don't use css much, how can i have the ripple effect on this button starting from right side of button to the left side. Basically changing the direction of the ripple effect.**

```
.button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:after {
  content: "";
  background: #90EE90;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 300%;
  padding-left: 350%;
  margin-left: -20px!important;
  margin-top: -120%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s
}

.button:active:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0s
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the ripple effect to start from the right side, simply add `right: 0;` to ".button:after". See example below. Tested and works.

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:after {
  content: "";
  background: #90EE90;
  display: block;
  right: 0; /* New code */
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 300%;
  padding-right: 350%;
  margin-left: -20px!important;
  margin-top: -120%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s
}

.button:active:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0s
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Click me</a>
```